# Counting the size of an array, inside an array element - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

So I'm trying to create a dynamic navigation bar that is built through menu items stored in a database.

Each menu item is assigned a parent_id, if that id is 0, that item is a parent; if that id is a value above 0, then that menu item is the child of another menu item. (Imagine hovering over a navigation menu item and getting a drop down of children items)

The following function is what builds the multi-dimensional array from the records in the database.

```
function build_menu($menu_id){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_errno;
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name`, `order`, `parent_id`, `path` FROM menu_items WHERE `group_id` = ? ORDER BY `order` ASC");
    $menu_id = intval($mysqli->real_escape_string($menu_id));
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $menu_id);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $results = resultToArray($stmt->get_result());
        $parents = array();
        $children = array();
        $menu = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++){
            if($results[$i]['parent_id'] === 0){
                $parents[] = $results[$i];
            } else {
                $children[] = $results[$i];
            }
        }

        for($i=0; $i<count($parents); $i++){
            $menu[$i] = $parents[$i];
            for($j=0; $j<count($children); $j++){
                if($children[$j]['parent_id'] === $parents[$i]['id']){
                    $menu[$i][$j] = $children[$j];
                }
            }
        }
        return($menu);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to execute statement: " . $stmt->errno . ": " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    return(0);
}
```

This is the function that takes that array and turns it into HTML code to be used as the navigation bar.

```
function get_menu($menu_id) {
    if(build_menu($menu_id)){
        $menu = build_menu($menu_id);

        $menu_html = '<ul>';
        for($i=0; $i<count($menu); $i++){
            $menu_item_path = ($menu[$i]['path'] != NULL ? $menu[$i]['path'] : '#');
            $menu_html .= '<li><a href="' . $menu_item_path . '">' . $menu[$i]['name'] . '</a>';
            if(count($menu[$i])>0){
                $menu_html .= '<ul>';
                for($j=0; $j<count($menu[$i]); $j++){
                    if(isset($menu[$i][$j])){
                        $menu_html .= '<li>' . $menu[$i][$j]['name'] . '</li>';
                    }
                }
                $menu_html .= '</ul>';
            }
            $menu_html .= '</li>';
        }
        $menu_html .= '</ul>';

        return($menu_html);
    }
    }
```

I presumed that `if(count($menu[$i])>0)` would count the array inside the selected element, but for some reason, it counts the keys and therefore always true.

I know this is a pretty long question, I do appreciate those of you that have read this far. If you can help me figure out a way to see if a menu item has children items, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

use array_filter to count only the items in array not empty or null

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I don't understand. I'm trying to see if an array exists inside an array element.

Comment: I've found a fix. Instead of counting the "sub-array", I just checked to see if `isset($menu[$i][0])` returned true, proving that a "sub-array" existed.

Answer (score 0):

Process of generating HTML menu can be a lot easier than your example.

```php
function generateMenu(array $menu, $parentId = 0) {
    if (!isset($menu[$parentId])) {
        return;
    }
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ($menu[$parentId] as $record) {
        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= '<a href="#">' . $record['title'] . '</a>';
        $output .= generateMenu($menu, $record['id']);
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}

echo generateMenu($menu);
```

Above code would output HTML like:

```
x First level #1
    o Second level #8
x First level #2
    o Second level #4
        - Third level #6
        - Third level #7
    o Second level #5
x First level #3
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/81041)</kbd>

But for that to work, you must fix your `build_menu()` function, to return array like [this](http://pastebin.com/ZdGaFBbY), which is very easy, just create one array `$menu` and fill it like `$menu[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;`, where `$row` is record row fetched from database.